# Problem with determining "security updates"

Tags: package-management, updates, security

My test machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.1.

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

says that 157 packages can be updated and 81 are security updates.

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^Inst" | grep -i security
```

says nothing, but without the last grep it mentions 157 packages.

Lynis says there are vulnerabilities, which I understand means that there are security updates.

So what is happening? Are there two definitions of "security updates?"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes.

From the function definition in /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py :

```
 def isSecurityUpgrade(ver):
     " check if the given version is a security update (or masks one) "
```

Did you notice **or masks one** ?

> How are the "-updates" and "-security" pockets different?
>
> -updates includes things that have gone through the StableReleaseUpdates process, and contain various important bug fixes.
>   Anything built for "-updates" is built on top of which ever version of
>   a package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that
>   nothing in "-updates" will introduce security regressions.
>
> -security includes only updated packages that contain security-related fixes, and are built to not require anything from "-updates". Anything
>   built for "-security" is built on top of which ever version of a
>   package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that nothing
>   in "-security" will introduce bug regressions.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Repositories

Follow the link for more details.

Comment: This answer seems to be about how maintainers determine that an update should be marked as security related. My question is about how software (apt-check or apt-get) determines whether an update has been marked as security related. Perhaps "masks" is the clue, but I do not understand it.

Comment: On this side this must be encapsulated in the rest of the function I presented, if not somewhere else. I'm not good enough in Python. But, as I understand it, the packages with references to -security marked ones bear the type mark. The client side following this logic should have this mechanism built in somewhere.